# Getting the Monday and Friday of next week

Tags: javascript, date

I need your help.

The current code below is able to calculate a date, a week (7 days) from the given date.

I'd like to have it amended such that it would take today's date and calculate the what the date (the Monday and Friday) will be on the following week.

Ie. today's date is: 12/10/2014 (mm/dd/yyyy)

The Monday of next week is: 12/15/2014

The Friday of next week is: 12/19/2014

```
function nextweek() {

    var currentDate = new Date();

    var w = new Date(currentDate.getTime() + 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

    var dd = w.getDate()

    var mm = w.getMonth() + 1

    var yyyy = w.getFullYear()

    return mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy

}
```

Comment: what effort have you made to figure out your problem, not just give us code for `nextWeek`?

Comment: Look into the `getDay()` method of the `Date` object.

Comment: You could look into the `DateJS` library. It's as simple as `Parse.date('next monday');`

Comment: `var d = new Date(); d.setDate(d.getDate() - d.getDay() + 7 + 1);` (start of week, + 7 days, + 1 for monday). Friday should be easy to figure out from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's some snippet of code adapted for a similar question I saw some time ago (can't remember the exact source, it was about getting monday of current week)

```js
Date.prototype.getNextWeekMonday = function() {
    var d = new Date(this.getTime());
    var diff = d.getDate() - d.getDay() + 1;
    if (d.getDay() == 0)
        diff -= 7;
    diff += 7; // ugly hack to get next monday instead of current one
    return new Date(d.setDate(diff));
};

Date.prototype.getNextWeekFriday = function() {
    var d = this.getNextWeekMonday();
    return new Date(d.setDate(d.getDate() + 4));
};

// You can then use it like this :

var date = new Date();
alert(date.getNextWeekMonday());
alert(date.getNextWeekFriday());
```

It should be tested on touchy days (sunday and monday) to ensure it returns the mondays and fridays from correct week.

Answer (score 0):

This just adds an element to HTML, but we can also have a text field where a user can give a desired date, process that input in via `event handling` and display `NextMonday`.

```
<html>
<head><title>DATE EXAMPLE</title></head>
<body>
<div id="date">

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var date = new Date("12/10/2014");
    var divElement = document.getElementById("date");
    divElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(""));
    var nextMonday = new Date(date.getMonth() + "/" + parseInt(date.getDate() + 7 - date.getDay() + 1) + "/"+ date.getFullYear());
    var newDate = new Date
    divElement.firstChild.nodeValue = nextMonday;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

getting `NextFriday` can be done in similar approach.